# Use a VPN-connected computer as bridge btween a server and an auxiliary computer

Tags: networking, vpn

My company allows only one VPN access at the time with the same creditentials to the database server, but I usually work with 2 computers, thus need double access.

This is the architecture I have in mind:

Computer B --(?)--> Computer A --(VPN)--> Company Server

The trick is to use Computer A as 'VPN bridge' between the Server and my second computer, this way I can use one creditential. But I don't know what type of connection to set between computer A and B.

Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: This may be useless, but have you considered RDC'ing into A since it appears to already has server access? I've seen companies do this before, so I figure some sort of remote connection would work. Your only other option would probably be to open a port on A and route all traffic from B to A, then connect from that.

Comment: Don't  you have a VPN capable router?